# SQL date question

Tags: sql-server, date-format

I'm a novice and need help.  Trying to pull data from a table that will return info (various investment trade info) from the previous business day.  Is there a command or function for that?  thx

Comment: First I would recommend starting at the [How to Ask](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) section of the site. Generally, if you're asking for code help you'll want to include an [MVCE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) with your question. This will help you get an exact answer to your specific question, rather than a general one. Finally, this is a pretty common problem with a lot of solutions out on the intertubes. Have you [tried here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9922756/7948962)?

Comment: MVCE - I am querying a table that has a column with a trade date.  I need to bring back the trade details (price, quantity - which are in different columns) from the table for trades from the previous day and eventually set it up to pull these details every day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of how you might solve your problem.  Assuming today's date of February 25, 2019.  I'm using the `DateAdd` function to calculate the previous business date based on your comment that you only care about skipping weekends and the query would only run Monday through Friday.

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (ID int, TradeDate date, Price int, Quantity int)
INSERT INTO @T(ID, TradeDate, Price, Quantity) VALUES
(1,'2019-02-22',10,5),
(2,'2019-02-25',20,10)

---------------
SET DATEFIRST 7;    --Assume first day of week is Sunday
DECLARE @PrevDate DATE = CASE 
        WHEN datepart(weekday, Getdate()) = 2   -- check for Monday
            THEN dateadd(day, - 3, getdate())   -- set @PrevDate to Friday
        ELSE dateadd(day, - 1, getdate())       -- else set @PrevDate to yesterday
        END

SELECT *
FROM @T
WHERE TradeDate >= @PrevDate
    AND TradeDate < CONVERT(DATE, getdate())
```

---

```
| ID | TradeDate  | Price | Quantity |
|----|------------|-------|----------|
| 1  | 2019-02-22 | 10    | 5        |
```

Comment: Thanks - I think this makes sense, however, I forgot to specify, that I need previous "business" date.  ie today, I need Friday, 2/22

Comment: @MoEngel - You would probably need a [Date Dimension](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/) table for that.  Only your company knows what the previous business date is with respect to holidays and such

Comment: Agree - however, for my purposes I only need to worry about weekdays and skipping over weekends